# Text next to checkbox, python

Tags: python, pdf-form

I am working on a pdf form and need to extract the text next to a checkbox from it.
I have already tried using getFields() function of pypdf2 library. However it's not working for me. Also tried pdfminer library which just gives me the coordinates of the text.
How can i do it using python? Please help.

Comment: Are you facing any specific issue? if you more specific more likely you get an answers in stackoverflow.

Comment: The issue is that I want to get the label of the checkbox which has been selected. At present I'm unable to do that.

Comment: @sj0820 You can use pdfminer.six to get the coordinates of the checkbox and then parse the text that is next to the checkbox. Do you have an example PDF file?